# multi touch in one image view at different time Android Studio

Tags: android, touch-event

I'm trying to handle a user touch listener on my image, I want to store all XY coordinates of an image view which touched pixels. as this image, 
senario :
user touch an image in first touch, I want to store XY coordinates
then user touch the same image for the second touch , also  I want to store XY coordinates
and so on.[mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKr7y.png)

Comment: Do you need to get the coordinate when you drag your finger?

Comment: with finger, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it help!

```
public class Coordinate {
        float x;
        float y;

        public Coordinate(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
}

ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

yourImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //int eventAction = event.getAction();
                //switch (eventAction) {
                //    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                            
                //        break;
                //    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //        break;
                //    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //      break;
                //}
                coordinates.add(new Coordinate(event.getX(), event.getY()));
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: its good , but only read the first touch, is there any way to count all touches?

Comment: I edited the answer, now you could get the coordinates when you tap the screen `(ACTION_DOWN)`, move your finger `(ACTION_MOVE)` and lift your finger up `(ACTION_UP)`